# ¿Como puedo mostrar una fecha en DatePicker que viene de una coleccion de mongod y se muestre en un formulario de edicion? estoy usando NodeJS y React

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, momentjs, ant-design

Tengo un registro en mongodb donde necesito posterior mente editarlo pero contiene fechas y mas strings, pero a la hora de darle editar, abre el modal para editar pero no me aparece la fecha de la colección.

[image: formulario de edicion]

ya le di formato de DD/MM/YYYY y si hago console.log si me trae las fechas pero en el Datepicker solo me da la fecha actual

[image: console.log]

esa es la fecha que me debería de mostrar pero me manda la fecha del día.

[image: datapicker con fecha del día y no de mongodb]

aquí es donde le doy formato a mi fecha que viene de la base con la data plecaData

```
 let fechainicio = moment.utc(plecaData.inicio).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
   
    console.log('inicio: ' +fechainicio) ;

    let fechafin = moment.utc(plecaData.fin).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    console.log('fin: '+fechafin)  ;
```

así es como la declaro en el Datapicker

```
 <Space direction="vertical">
                    <DatePicker 
                    placeholder="inicio"
                    onChange={e => setPlecaData({ ...plecaData, inicio: e })}
                    defaultValue={moment(fechainicio, dateFormatList)} format={dateFormatList}    
                    
                    name="inicio"
                    />
                </Space>
```

Comment: cuando haces click en editar como tu dices, tienes que traer todos los datos de cierto contexto del que hablas, como estas trayendo esos datos y como se ven ?

Comment: Hola, y gracias por el interes, los campos estan en una tabla echa con Material Table la cual en esta parte con el evento onClick mando llamar los campos   ``````<MaterialTable
             icons={tableIcons}
            columns={columnas}
            data={plecasInactive}
            title="Plecas Inactivas"
            setReloadAltaPleca={setReloadAltaPleca}
            actions={[
              {
                icon: Edit,
                tooltip: 'Editar Pleca',
                onClick: (event, pleca)=>editPleca(pleca)
               }
            ]}`````

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolvi estaba colocando defaultvalue y lo cambie por value y ya me da la fecha que viene de mongodb..

``````
                     
                    placeholder="fin"
                    onChange={e => setPlecaData({ ...plecaData, fin: e })}
                    value={moment(fechafin, dateFormatList)} format={dateFormatList}  
                    name="fin"
                    allowClear={false}
                    autoenfoque={true}
                    />`````
``````